# Convert table into physical file AS400/DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

EDITED for clarity:

I've created a table in DB2 using SQL.
I have now realized that I did not know the record format for the physical file created and need a Logical File to define keys to use in the RPG code. How can I accomplish this using SQL rather than DDS?

This was what I wanted to ask, really, now that I know a lot more on the subject.

Comment: A table created with SQL is a physical file.  Start over so you don't confuse your co-workers.

Comment: Accomplish 'what' with SQL? If you're asking how to create a SQL index, run a SQL CREATE INDEX statement. Or are you asking about record formats, and if so, what about them?

Comment: @therealchx101  See how you have to start over the answer below is a create statement.  Start over.

Answer (score 4):

There's really no difference between a PF created with DDS and a table created with SQL DDL.

Both methods result in a *FILE object with an attribute of PF.

The resulting object from either method can be used with SQL or with RPG record level access (RLA).

You can create DDS LF's or SQL views/indexes over a DDS created PF or an SQL DDL created table.

IBM provides tools to generate SQL DDL for a DDS created object, but not the other way around. You might be able to find a 3rd party tool designed to generate DDS if you lose your DDS source.

Best practice now-a-days is to use SQL DDL; as many recent enhancements to the DB are not available when using DDS.

If you think you need to use DDS for compatibly with RPG for instance, you are incorrect.  All you need to do is take advantage of IBM i specific keywords.

Instead of

```
create table my_long_table_name (
  my_long_column_name  char(10)
);
```

Use

```
create table my_long_table_name      
         for system name mytable (   
  my_long_column_name                
     for mycol char(10)              
) rcdfmt mytabler;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out

Comment: Good morning Charles. I've tried out the "for" keyword but I got a syntax error...
"Keyword FOR not expected"

Comment: The rcdfmt in the end is supposed to have a different name than the table?

Comment: Show your source. The example Charles gave works without error. Without source, we can't help you.

Comment: `RCDFMT` name can be whatever you want....historically, DDS files had a record format name different than the PF name.

Comment: It's precisely with the example that I'm having the problems I'm having. I ended up editing some Physical an d Logical files, uploading and compiling them to achieve the result I needed. Later on I guess it was not possiple to do what I wanted...